# prepared statement for insert in ms access DB

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a problem while inserting data in my MS Access database when I add two more fields `date` and `birthdate`. It gives a syntax error in insert statement. I was suggested to use a `PreparedStatement`, however it is not clear to me what changes I have to made in my code. Can anyone explain it to me?

```
int regno= Integer.parseInt(cbregn.getSelectedItem().toString()); //regno=pkey
String nm= cbnm.getSelectedItem().toString();
String place=tfplace.getText();
String kul=tfkul.getText();
String gotra=tfgotra.getText();
String kswami=tfswami.getText();
String raddr=taraddr.getText();
int pincode=Integer.parseInt(tfpcd.getText());//taken datatype number for pincode
int stdcd=Integer.parseInt(tfstdcode.getText());//taken datatype number for stdcode
int tele=Integer.parseInt(tftele.getText());//taken datatype number for teleph no
int mno=(int) Long.parseLong(tfmno.getText());//taken datatype number for mobileno
String email=tfemail.getText();
String website=tfweb.getText();
String education=tfedu.getText();
String branch=tfbrch.getText();
int brthdt=Integer.parseInt(tfbdt.getText());
String bloodgroup=(String)cbbldgrp.getSelectedItem();

try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:wanisamajDB");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    String qry= "INSERT INTO Registration1(RegistrationNo,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BloodGroup) VALUES('"+regno+"','"+nm+"','"+place+"','"+kul+"','"+gotra+"','"+kswami+"','"+raddr+"','"+pincode+"','"+stdcd+"','"+tele+"','"+mno+"','"+email+"','"+website+"','"+education+"','"+branch+"','"+bloodgroup+"')";
    // String qry= "INSERT INTO Registration1(RegistrationNo,SeniorPerson,NativePlace,Kul,Gotra,KulSwami,ResidensialAddress,PinCode,STDcode,TelephoneNo,MobileNo,Email,Website,Education,Branch,BloodGroup,Date,BirthDate) VALUES('"+regno+"','"+nm+"','"+place+"','"+kul+"','"+gotra+"','"+kswami+"','"+raddr+"','"+pincode+"','"+stdcd+"','"+tele+"','"+mno+"','"+email+"','"+website+"','"+education+"','"+branch+"','"+bloodgroup+"','"+date+"','"+brthdt+"')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(qry);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS SAVED SUCCESSFULLY ");
    con.close();
}
catch(SQLException eM) {
    System.out.println(" "+eM);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"RECORD IS NOT SAVED");
} 
catch(Exception et)
{
    System.out.println("error:"+et.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This is a popular question recently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5570897/error-in-insert-into-statement

Answer (score 0):

Put this

```
System.out.println(qry);
```

in, under the

```
String qry = "...";
```

Then paste your output in MSAccess. The error will be a bit more clear. Furthermore i see you parse your birthdate ( `brthd`t ) to an `int`. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

when you use such a long statment, involving so many parametrs - it is almost imposible not doing mistakes.
i highly recomend using preparedStatment.

If you still insist using statment, 
try print the string to the console and see if you missing apostrophe or comma in your statment.